# Visual Studio Setup project with some minor custom actions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am new to creating an installer for Visual Studio 2010 and I have been learning a bit about the Setup projects.

So far so good, the basic out-of-the-box installer works just fine, but I need to find out how to copy an XML file in my main project into a certain, very specific directory during the installation process.

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So thanks to JP, I now know that I need to create a Custom Folder in the File System section of the project, which I have done, and also set that directory to be the required directory that my .lnk file needs to go.

But for some unknown reason, I cannot add the .lnk file to the Custom Folder, it just doesnt appear after I hit "open" in the file chooser dialog box. Other file types work just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [file system editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2a99e5c.aspx).  If it's a standard folder like the Application Folder or the Desktop, use that.  Otherwise, right click on "File System on Target Machine" and choose "Add Special Folder" -> "Custom Folder".  Then set the directory in the properties of the special folder you made.  Then you can add your file to the setup project with right click on the project->add file or you can add a standard file type (output, source, etc).  Then, set the folder property on the file you created to the custom folder you made.

Comment: Thanks JP, almost go it, I got up to "Then set the directory in the properties of the special folder you made" but it seems that I cannot add a .lnk file (which is a shortcut to my XML file) to that custom folder, is this a know issue?

Comment: I can get around this by including the actual XML file, but I need to replace certain paths in the XML file with the installer directory, can this be done?

Comment: Ahhh I got it, sorry you had the XML file to the setup project, then in the custom folder you add a shortcut to it (right click in the right hand pane of the custom folder and click add shortcut)... thanks!